# Breakpoints not working in xamarin uwp in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, uwp, breakpoints

I am new in Xamarin Forms. Using xamarin application breakpoints work very well under Android but fails with UWP.

Checking option <kbd>project → Properties → Build → "Compile using the native code tool chain"</kbd> causes navigation to not work.

NB: vs 2017 is up to date (version 15.5.7)

Comment: the French part... "compile using the native code tool chain" ? is it?

Comment: Please localize your error messages to english before. And by localize, I **don't** mean google translate.

Comment: It might be that the project is not rebuilt for the given configuration. Could you try doing Clean solution and then Rebuild solution? Also make sure you have set the x86 platform instead of Any CPU as target

Comment: Did you mean you checked Compile using the native code tool chain? Did you run the app in debug mode?

Answer (score 23):

This can happen if xamarin is used with .net standard, by default the shared library uses the 'portable' debug mode, if it is changed to 'Full' it should work correctly.
Go to Project properties -> build -> Advanced -> Debuggingh information and set Full.